# Having trouble passing parameters to a program within powershell

Tags: java, powershell, yui-compressor

I'm using yuicompressor to minify and obfuscate some javscript files. I'm trying to dynamically build the file path and pass it to the minifier from powershell.

Here's what works:

```
$results = java -jar c:\yui\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar c:\MyFile.js -v --charset utf-8
```

Here's what doesn't work:

```
$yuiPath = "c:\yui\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar"
$filePath = "c:\MyFile.js"

$results = java -jar $yuiPath $filePath -v --charset utf-8
```

It's apparently not liking the `$filePath -v --charset utf-8` part because I successfully get the yuicompressor help text when I run it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The path to the file "c:\MyFile" didn't actually have the extension so I needed to pass `--type js` as an argument

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use Join-Path cmdlet and try it out.